# Rewrite PostgreSQL query for Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, window-functions

Please help me to rewrite it so that it will run on Heroku, where PostgreSQL (8.3.11) does not understand `over` keyword.

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    round(max(hspeed) * 2.238) as chs,
    percent_rank() over (partition by con_size_id ORDER BY MAX(hspeed))
FROM
    summaries ss
    INNER JOIN spaths s ON ss.spath_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN cons c ON c.id = s.con_id
    INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE
    con_size_id = 1
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    con_size_id;
```

"user_id" and "con_size_id" are from "cons" table, "hspeed" is from "summaries".

Comment: Does Heroku support full ANSI SQL 92 syntax?

Comment: I doubt that "over" is from ANSI SQL 92. They say that this syntax is available in PG 9.1 which can be used only with production database. They say: Pretty much full ANSI-SQL 92 compliance and a lot of ANSI 99 compliance (http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=11)

Comment: PostGres supports `Percent_Rank()`.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html

Comment: PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "over"

Comment: [This page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) contains substantially similar syntax as your example.  So basically you're saying that the version of PostGres that Heroku uses is too old?

Comment: select version() says: "PostgreSQL 8.3.11 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)". Link you have suggested contains the PostgreSQL 9.1.4 Documentation.

Comment: PostgreSQL got window functions in 8.4, your Heroku database is still using 8.3. Can you upgrade to a dedicated database or the 9.1? See http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/1/heroku_s_new_free_postgresql_9_1_development_database/

Comment: The situation is as follows: My superiors bought two Heroku applications where PostgreSQL can be theoretically upgraded to 9.1, but I have several free own Heroku applications for debugging. They won't pay for them, I too. I even do not have a credit card.

Comment: The databases upgrade that 'mu is too short' has linked to is free on the Dev plan and runs Postgres 9.1.3 - this is a recently released Heroku option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to upgrade to 8.4 or higher.  8.3 and lower does not reasonably support the required functionality without a lot of complicated user defined functions wrapping your queries.